# Origin VS Authority and Domain certificates and Unique IPs

Tags: tls, certificates, http, certificate-authority, cors

*Disclaimer, I am new to InformationSecurity, so sorry if I not following rules as good as expected. I asked this post on stackOverflow, and I was suggested to transfer it here*

So far I get:

- Origin = Schema (i.e. https) + host + port (may implicit)
- Authority = Userinfo (rarely use) + host + port

and while Domain Certificates applies for Fully-Qualified domains, WildCard Domains and Multiple Domains [i.e. list of  sub-domains], but indeed only for https (so it gets schema implicitly)

on the other hand, the DNS resolution (some vendors) allow a domain IP forwarding, dedicated subdomain to different IP addresses, and a wildcard forwarding to another IP [ as sub-domains to identify services, aka protocols, still used sometimes :_( ]

therefore:

- two petitions to different schemas may share the same Authority but not Origins (avoiding CORS) and  neither Certificates, what about other protocols as RTP, RTSP, SSH, FTP or SMTP ??
  **is that limiting protocol usage on secured web applications?**
- while not a common use practice, UserInfo may be user for some short of identification/segmentation, 
  **does it make it incompatible with SSL Certificates?**
- and lastly, on a scenario with several sub-domains identifying different machines (diferente IPs)
  **does it gets to validate the same wildcard/multidomain certificate across machines??**

read RFCs, plenty of info, and plenty of stackOverflow questions, still confused between those terms

lastly, and just to be sure, other than schema/authority/host/ports, nothing else have something to do with security within the URI, right?
(I mean, any part of the path, or query, or so on)

**"the purpose of this question is to clearly understand where all this concepts/terms collide, I believe I have good understanding of the OSI model and have read enough available documentation, but something still in gray area"**